# Heroku postgres not found

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

When I go to my Apps in Heroku and check the resources I can see Postgresql

but when I run from my computer pg:info I get the following:

```
$ heroku pg:info
! Resource not found
```

or this:

```
$  heroku pg:wait 
!    Resource not found
```

although when I run pg:credential I do get an output:

```
$ heroku pg:credentials HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK
Connection info string:
   "dbname=some_name host=ec2-107-22-165-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=some_user password=some_password sslmode=require"
```

I have tried running `heroku run rake db:migrate`, `heroku run db:reset` and all fail.
I get the errors:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Going to the settings through the heroku web, I can see the following:

```
Connection Settings : Default

Host    ec2-107-22-165-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Database    some_databasename
User    some_user
Port    5432
Password    some_password

Statistics
Plan    Dev
Status  available
Data Size   5.9 MB
Tables  0
PG Version  9.1.8
Created March 27, 2013 18:01
```

`heroku config` has DATABASE_URL and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL set.

I have erased the `production` section of `database.yml` as I understand Heroku creates its own `database.yml`

I just migrated to ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0

how should I connect to the database? I thought this was supposed to be automatic. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by downgrading Rails and Ruby :(

Now I'm using rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Remove "localhost" connection in your app :)

Comment: @catsby what do you mean removing localhost connection?, the gal removed the production entry in the database.yml file.

Comment: A Heroku Postgres database is not at "localhost" on Heroku, it's at $DATABASE_URL. The app was trying to connect to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with an outdated heroku toolbelt version. I was using v2.19.2.

Installing heroku toolbelt via ruby gems is deprecated, best thing to do is uninstall heroku gem `$ gem uninstall heroku` and reinstall the toolbelt the prefered way, depending on your platform: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/