# Heroku pg:info and pg:psql "Not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not sure what has happened to my heroku postgres but when I try to access it with command line with `pg:info` and `pg:psql`, I get "Not found".

I even clicked on the button on heroku to create a database for my app as well.

How do I debug this? What can I try? I don't mind starting from scratch since it's for testing.

Comment: Have you installed the heroku toolbelt?

Comment: Yeah, I can run commands like `heroku config`

Comment: Mine does the same, if you pass the app name it work `heroku pg:info --app <appname>`

Comment: @JohnBeynon Are you able to run pg:psql?

Comment: yes. Same method with --app <appname> on the end.

Comment: Weird. When I tried `heroku pg:psql --app foo` I get `!    Unknown database. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL`. So I tried `heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL` then I get `!    Not found` again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try passing the appname or database name explicitly. The heroku cli tries to infer your application name from the 'heroku' git remote but if it can't find that it just returns the Not Found message.

eg;

```
heroku pg:info --app appname
```

Comment: This still works in 2021, and just the fix I needed too, many thanks!

Answer (score 20):

It wants the psql installed and avalibale on the command line **on your local machine**. On Ubuntu, I ran `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client` . `heroku pg:psql` then worked straight away.

Comment: This fixed it for me, and it didn't seem obvious in the first place.

Comment: Using apt-get in Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

Comment: If `apt-get` isn't installed, try `sudo yum install postgresql-server`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are one **OS X** you should **install postgres** like this :

`brew install postgres`

Answer (score 0):

See this. May be the same reason. 
[Heroku postgres not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667551/heroku-postgres-not-found)